# How can I use the Review Order Pane twice in Commerce Checkout?

Tags: commerce

I'd like to be able to use the Review Order pane twice in the Commerce Checkout... first before the customer enters payment and then again when they Confirm the order.

Or do I need to create a new Pane?

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't completely tried this out, but you can duplicate the pane by implementing [hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter/7). Something like:

```
function mymodule_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_panes) {
  $checkout_panes['my_checkout_review'] = $checkout_panes['checkout_review'];
  $checkout_panes['my_checkout_review']['title'] = '[Duped] Review'; // to differentiate
}
```

I don't know what the consequences are of having two review panes, but I think this would be a good starting point.